# C# OleDbConnection

Tags: console-application, oledb

I have "Multiple-step OLEDB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done." OleDbException while trying the following connection string:

```
source = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Teacher;integrated security=true;"
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(source);
conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you have an error in your connection string. Try changing the "integrated security=true" to "integrated security=SSPI" like below:

```
source = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Teacher;integrated security=SSPI;"
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(source);
conn.Open();
```

If that doesn't work, try connecting to SQLEXPRESS using SQL Server authentication, i.e. with username and password (in order for this work you need to allow mixed type authentication in SQL Server):

```
source = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Teacher;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;"
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(source);
    conn.Open();
```

Let us know the result.